# Why are the login boxes on the left and how can I easily move them to the center?

Tags: lightdm

I wonder why Ubuntu chose to put the login forms at LightDM in the left instead of centering it. I find it totally ugly and a mental effort when I boot up and try to find the login with my eyes wandering from the center to the left.

Are there any reasons for designing it the way it is? (I could not find anything on the Ubuntu wiki.)

Would there be a super simple way to center everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My opinion is that it was a design decision that had to do with showing the wallpaper.  For detailed wallpaper the "focus" for the image is typically the center.  Placing the login box centered would obstruct the view of the wallpaper.

If you really prefer it old-school, just install the "old" display manager, GDM, via `sudo apt-get install gdm`. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LightDM cannot be configured to show the login boxes in the center - you will have to use KDM or GDM for that.